# BoundField: assign localized resource property as DataFormatString

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is it possible to use localized resource strings with DataFormatString? If it is, what is the syntax? I've tried to assign to the property the following ways without avail:

```
<asp:BoundField DataFormatString='<%$ Resources:LocalizedText,ShortDateFormat %>' />
```

Result: `yyyy-MM-dd`

```
<asp:BoundField DataFormatString='{0:<%$ Resources:LocalizedText,ShortDateFormat %>}' />
```

Result: `<$ Re21ource21:Locali+1e14Tex,S2orDae8or13a >`

```
<asp:BoundField DataFormatString='<%= LocalizedText.ShortDateFormat %>' />
```

Result: `yyyy-MM-dd`

```
<asp:BoundField DataFormatString='<%# "{0:" + LocalizedText.ShortDateFormat + "}" %>' />
```

Result: malformed tag exception.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by creating an additional resource string `ShortDateFormatString` that essentially contains the `{0:}` that is necessary for the formatter to understand the notation.

Answer (score 1):

Good morning have you tried the following:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataFormatString='{0:<%= LocalizedText.ShortDateFormat %>}' />
```

**UPDATE:**
And if you try this way does it still not give you the correct result:

```
 DataFormatString="{0:<%$ Resources:LocalizedText,ShortDateFormat %>}"
```

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately.  Result: `<= Locali+1e14Tex.S2orDae8or13a >`.